# Android how to perform drag n drop with listview items

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

I created a application where i fetch the database and dynamically created that many checkbox & textview
now i want to perform drag n drop events with that list items.

How can i do this, plz give me a way

Comment: means what you want to do ? are you want to reorder listview items ?

Comment: yes.It also affect on databse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

from API lev 11 only :-(

Comment: this only works on 3.0+, the music on 2.1.1 has a drag and drop feature for the playlists.

@Jyosna, download and look at the android source code for the music player: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=summary

Comment: please give me a sample example so that i can understand

Comment: The problem is, that while you are coding for the API level 11, you have nice tools created for drag and drop. But for lower levels, and they are what almost all real gadgets have, you have to code everything by hand. Or use some code created by smb else. So, look for that reference of raybritton and try to use the code there.  Of course, if you are making a training example on emulator only, use API level 11 freely.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try my component, called DragSortListView. You can find it here:

- https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview